# Let $f : \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} \to S^1$, $f(x) = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$. Show that $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.

Tags: general-topology

> Let $f : \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} \to S^1$, $f(x) = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$. Show that $f$ is a homotopy equivalence.

I was instructed that the inclusion map should be helpful here, but if I let $g : S^1 \to \Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} $ be the inclusion then $f \circ g = f(g(x)) = f(x)$ but is this homotopic to $id_{S^1}$? Initially I thought that $f \circ g = id_{S^1}$, but for example $$f(1,1) = (\frac{1}{\sqrt2}, \frac{1}{\sqrt2}) \ne id_{S^1}(1,1)?$$

I’m not sure if $id_{S_1}(1,1)$ is even defined since $(1,1) \notin S^1$?

Also $g \circ f = g(f(x)) = f(x) = id_X$?

What might I be doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In fact your first thought was correct, $f \circ g = id_{S^1}$.

You are right, $id_{S^1}(1,1)$ is undefined. However, that is not an impediment to proving the equation $f \circ g = id_{S^1}$, because the functions $id_{S^1}$, and $g$, and $f \circ g$, all have the same domain, and that domain is $S^1$. Therefore $f \circ g(1,1)$ is also undefined.

I suggest that when you when write out an equation of functions that you need to prove are equal or are homotopic, you *very carefully* keep track of the domains and ranges of the functions. So, in this case what you are trying to prove is
$$f \circ g = id_{S^1} : S^1 \to S^1
$$
Writing it this way makes it very clear **how** to prove this... which is almost what you did, but your mathematical grammar needs some improvement. Here's the correct proof:

> Given $x \in S^1$, we must prove $f \circ g(x)=id_{S^1}(x)$:
>
> $f \circ g(x) = f(g(x)) = f(x) = x = id_{S^1}(x)$

Comparing this with what you wrote in the last lines, I suggest that you be very careful about using function notation correctly, in particular that you use function *arguments* correctly. Your proof has two violations of the grammar of function arguments: neither your equation $f \circ g = f(g(x))$ nor your equation $f(x)=id_{S^1}$ makes any sense.

Comment: Thanks for the informative answer. Only thing I’m concerned with is that is it neccessary that $x \in S^1$, when proving $f \circ g = id_{S^1}$? Isn’t $f \circ g$ defined from $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} \to S^1$, so $x$ could be in $\Bbb R^2 \setminus \{0\} $?

Comment: As I indicated wrote in my answer, the domain of the composed function $f \circ g$ is the the same as the domain of the function $g$. You might want to do a little review of functions, their domains, their codomains (also called ranges), and the definition of function composition. Some good topology books, such as Munkres, have a "Chapter 0" in which they review these things.

Comment: But this is also pretty straightforward to understand on an intuitive level. The definition of function composition is $f \circ g(x) = f(g(x))$. How can you possibly plug in a value of $x$ which is *not* in the domain of $g$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x\in S^1$, $\|x\|=1$ implies that $f(x)=x$, it results that $f\circ g(x)=f(x)=x$ and $f\circ g$ is homotopic to $Id_{S^1}$.

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$, $g\circ f(x)=g({x\over{\|x\|}})={x\over{\|x\|}}=f(x)$.

Consider $H_t(x)=tx+(1-t){x\over{\|x\|}}$ defined in $\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}$, t\in [0,1].
$H_t$ is well defined, $tx+(1-t){x\over{\|x\|}}=0$ implies that $t\|x\|+(1-t)=0$,
$(1-\|x\|)t=1$. This implies that

$t={1\over{1-\|x\|}}$, it $\|x\|<1, t>1$ impossible, $t$ is not defined if $\|x\|=1$ and if $\|x\|>1, t<0$ impossible, this implies that $H_t$ is well defined, $H_0(x)=g\circ f(x)=f(x), H_1(x)=x$, implies that $g\circ f=f $ is homotopic to $Id_{\mathbb{R}^2-\{0\}}$.